# reprojecting a raster in R error "could not find function "wkt"

Tags: r, r-raster, rgdal, reprojection-error

I've been working with raster data and the code has been working fine. Unexpectedly when reprojecting with:

```
reproject()
```

I get

> "Error in wkt(projfrom) :could not find function "wkt".

I'm using CRS arguments:

```
 +proj=utm +zone=5 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

I have also tried `projectRaster()` and get a similar error.

Might be an issue with the rgdal package? Anyone else getting this?

Answer (score 1):

This problem should go away if you update the `sp` package

Comment: Well, I use R 4.0.4, and just updated packages raster, sp, rgdal, dismo, rJava, rgeos, and maptools. Still getting a message 'Error in wkt(r) : could not find function "wkt" '. Any idea why it could happen? Thanks.

Comment: Do the examples in `?projectRaster` work for you? They work fine for me with R and current packages.

Comment: No, unfortunately they don't. 
> ?projectRaster

Warning message:
no function found corresponding to methods exports from ‘raster’ for: ‘wkt’ 

> wkt(r)

Error in wkt(r) : could not find function "wkt"

Comment: Then suggest that you are not using current R. Can you report the first three lines returned by `sessionInfo()`; and confirm that further down it prints `raster_3.4-5 sp_1.4-5 `?

Comment: Your comment prompted me to restart my computer and install sp again. And everything works now! Thank you so much for your time and sorry i didn't do it earlier - my R version was showing as 4.0.4. immediately after I reinstalled R.